# How can I arrange to pattern match on a dependent view?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I've written some simple types for viewing `Vect` values:

```
data SnocVect : Vect n a -> Type where
  SnocNil : SnocVect []
  Snoc : (xs : Vect n a) -> (x : a) -> SnocVect (xs ++ [x])

data Split : (m : Nat) -> Vect n a -> Type where
  MkSplit : (xs : Vect j a) -> (ys : Vect k a) ->
              Split j (xs ++ ys)
```

Now it seems to me entirely reasonable that if I have a `Split` separating the last element of a vector, I should be able to convert that into a `SnocVect`:

```
splitToSnocVect : .{xs : Vect (S n) a} -> Split n xs ->
    SnocVect xs
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any way to implement this thing. In particular, I haven't found any way whatsoever to get it to let me pattern match on the `Split n xs` argument, without which I obviously can't get anywhere. I *think* the basic problem is that I have something of type

```
Split j (ps ++ [p])
```

and since `++` isn't injective, I need to work some sort of magic to convince the type checker that things make sense. But I don't understand this well enough to say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it! I imagine there *must* be a better way, but this works.

```
vectLengthConv : {auto a : Type} -> m = n ->
                    Vect m a = Vect n a
vectLengthConv prf = rewrite prf in Refl

splitToSnocVect' : .(n : Nat) -> .(xs : Vect m a) ->
              .(m = n+1) -> Split n xs -> SnocVect xs
splitToSnocVect' n (ys ++ zs) prf (MkSplit {k} ys zs) 
     with (vectLengthConv (plusLeftCancel n k 1 prf))

  splitToSnocVect' n (ys ++ []) prf
      (MkSplit {k = Z} ys []) | Refl impossible

  splitToSnocVect' n (ys ++ (z :: [])) prf 
     (MkSplit {k = (S Z)} ys (z :: [])) | lenconv =
        Snoc ys z

  splitToSnocVect' n (ys ++ zs) prf 
    (MkSplit {k = (S (S k))} ys zs) | Refl impossible

splitToSnocVect : .{n : Nat} -> .{xs : Vect (S n) a} ->
                       Split n xs -> SnocVect xs
splitToSnocVect {n} {xs} splt =
    splitToSnocVect' n xs (plusCommutative 1 n) splt
```

#### Edit

David Christiansen suggests nixing `vectLengthConv` and instead using `cong {f=\len=>Vect len a} (plusLeftCancel n k 1 prf)` in the `with` clause. This helps a little.